# Dynamics CRM Webhooks

Tags: azure, azure-functions, dynamics-crm, webhooks, dynamics-crm-webapi

I want to integrate our Sales CRM dynamics system with another application. Approaches we are considering are using web api and webhooks.

- Can we use webhooks without using an azure function/azure service?
- what all are the challenges?
- Is there any other better methods to pull data from Dynamics CRM?
- What all things should be considered while doing an integration with Dynamics CRM system?

(I am new to Dynamics)
link followed:https://dynamicsninja.blog/2019/05/22/d365-webhooks-part-1/

Comment: It's an interesting question, but unfortunately I don't think you'll get a good answer here. There are a lot of different requirements for integration so I think this question will be closed as "too broad"

Comment: go webapi \odata if the integration is light weigth enough, flow or logic apps can also do the trick easyly enough.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a relatively simple integration, using Power Automate might be your best bet.

https://flow.microsoft.com/

To answer your specific questions, though:

- Can we use webhooks without using an azure function/azure service?

  - No. You'll need to use Power Automate, Logic Apps, or some other method to watch for changes.
- what all are the challenges?

  - That's a pretty broad question, can't help you without specific things you've already tried.
- Is there any other better methods to pull data from Dynamics CRM? What all things should be considered while doing an integration with Dynamics CRM system?

  - If you're just doing reporting (pulling data) then PowerBI is a good choice, otherwise it's the API for custom integration or Power Automate/Logic Apps for something that needs a little less customization.

Answer (score -1):

If you realy want to have a CRM fully integrated i would consider to try

• Power Automate (as said before): it's a good way to easily connect several systems

• Azure Functions: Sometimes power automate is just not enough but with azure functions you can easily create some serverless code. I have some aazure functions that are triggered by receiving a message in a queue by power automate for example. You can make both work together and that what we have at work :)

The biggets challeng is the "know-how" I guess. A lot of people do not know it yet. Azure functions can be a little difficult at the beggining (even more if you want to use early bound classes for you CRM). With some time you will get it.

Answer (score -1):

If you want do distribute your tool as a dynamics solution package which than should be added to an organisation without generating API token in azure and stuff like that i would suggest you don't pull data from dynamics (that way you need to authorize at the ms webapi with a token generated in azure and so on). Instead use web components and plugins triggered by core messages to push the data to your api.